# How to populate data in jstree in Grails?

Tags: javascript, grails, jstree

I'm still struggling to populate a jstree inside a Grails gsp. What I have so far is this (re-typed so forgive syntax errors):

```
<script>
    $("#treeView").jsTree();
</script>

<div id="treeView">
    <g:each in="${atomMap}">
        <li id="root"><a href="#">${it.key}<li>
            <ul>
                <g:each in="${it.value}">
                    <li><a href="#">${it.value}</a></li>
                </g:each>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </g:each>
</div>
```

My data displays on the page as a list of bullets, then the jstree overwrites it with empty data. How do I associate the data in "atomMap" to the tree itself? All of the examples I see use static data for "html_data" in the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - I was missing the outer  tags.